# Arguments for pd.plotting.scatter_matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to learn about machine learning and python. The video I am watching included this as code:

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df,c=y,figsize=[8,s=150],marker='D')
```

I have no idea what the `s` is in `figsize`. I checked the documentation for `scatter_matrix`, and that doesn't seem to help either.

Can someone also please explain what `c` means. Where am i supposed to learn what these things are? The documentation for `scatter_matrix` barely lists anything...

Comment: s is the size of the marker if I remember correctly. And c should be color

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! Have you tried just launching the code? Even if you don't understand each part of it, it can help you understanding it, for instance by changing some arguments values.

I am not a `pandas` user, but from the `scatter_matrix` documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html), it appears that `s` should be the height in inches, whereas the first number is the width.

As of `c`, it is a keyword argument for the `scatter` function, called by `scatter_matrix`. It is only the color used in the plot (see `scatter` documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)). For instance, `c="r"` or `c=[1,0,0]` will draw red dots.

To help you with the different python argument types (default, keyword, arbitraty), please check [this site](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-function-arguments/).